# TP-Link AC1750 install with installation CD, no ethernet, on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, software-installation

Attempting to install the software for a TP-Link AC 1750 PCIe adapter, model no. Archer T8E on Ubuntu 16.04.
I did research before buying this to replace a Netgear adapter (which I had for a while and discovered was useless with Linux).  According to multiple forums and the reviews on its Newegg page, the TP-Link adapter should work without need for software install.  Unfortunately this is not the case, and every question/answer I've seen has involved the use of (A) Ethernet or (B) A installation USB/CD with Linux adapted files. 
The installation CD contains files only for Windows, and won't allow me to open its setup.exe file.  (I'm new here, does Linux like .exe files in the first place?) 
I suppose what I'm asking is if I can install the adapter with files downloaded from another computer to a USB, without Ethernet and without sudo apt-get or any other non-default program.

If this could be fixed using an older installation of Linux itself, then that is also an option.  I've used Linux on a laptop before but this particular installation has not been used so I have no attachment to it.  Any advice or direct help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Readout for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` is `Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4310] (rev 03) Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]`
My kernel driver is `bcma-pci-bridge`

Comment: First, let's identify the adapter. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Done.  Any other information I should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no information at all that is available to suggest the correct driver. I am fairly certain that, based on modaliases, it is not b43/bcma, brcmsmac nor brcmfmac. The most likely possibility is brcmwl-kernel-source.

If you have the installation USB or DVD, insert it and and drill down to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d > dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: You see, my problem is that no such path exists.  I can't drill down to pool > restricted etc. because it isn't there.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install? `lsb_release -d` and also: `arch`.

Comment: `lsb_release -d` Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: `arch` response is X86_64

Comment: They are both there according to this: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.list

Comment: /pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb and also: /pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb Did you install from a USB or DVD or...??

Comment: Oh!  Every single answer I saw said installation disc/USB and I kept thinking they meant the installation for the adapter, but you meant installation for the OS!  I just didn't understand.  You may as well mark this as a duplicate unless you think it's worth keeping.  Thank you for your help, I'm connected to the wifi now.

Comment: Awesome! We shall add the pci.id 14e4:4310 to the Broadcom list now. Glad it's working.